# How to decide function in which component? (React)

Tags: react-hooks

I start to learn React. I try to create a little blog. The blog's part of structure likes this.

```
--blog
  --Artiecle
  --button
```

Now, I want to post an article. I get textarea's value from article component. But, onClick action is in button component.

I have two thoughts.

- put in button component. Because, that is the actual trigger position.
- put in blog component. Because, blog is common parent component.

I find some information about Hook Rule, layers or decomposition and try to read some side project.
Maybe I should not isolate button component. Or it's just personal style,

Comment: The common pattern is the parent component managing a `handleClick` event and passing it as a prop `onClick` to `<Button>`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I need to make some changes.